# How to post a dynamic image to wordpress post?

Tags: image, wordpress

I want to put a image into a post, but it seems I just cannot get it work.
For example, this one:
http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=ACHN&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=t88400486500&r=9913

The output is a PNG file. So in HTML tab, i put,
< img  src="http://stockcharts.com/c-sc/sc?s=ACHN&p=D&b=5&g=0&i=t88400486500&r=9913">,(I leave a empty space between the < and image otherwise, stackoverflow won't allow me to put a image tag here) it just won't show up the correct image. The image you will see is "go to stockcharts.com to view this chart", that is because the URL is wrong. If the URL is correct, the image will display fine. Any way to work around?
I was trying to play around with the formatting.php file, but so far, no luck.
(It is quite strange though, if you put the URL into your IE URL bar, and press enter, it shows up fine with a chart.)

Thanks.

Comment: That URL is giving me "Go to stockcharts.com to view this chart" for me in a browser.

Comment: SO does allow you load images use the help to find out how

Comment: After a deeper look, looks like it is StockCharts.com, it blocks any un-local request source. 
aharon, if you put your mouse at the end of the url in URL address bar, press enter, it will load the image fine. I think that is because the request is from local in that case. Not sure if i am right though.

Comment: It is not uncommon for websites to block direct links to their images. It is trivial to do and keeps people from freeloading on your servers. Here is an article on doing so in Apache - http://www.selfseo.com/story-18469.php

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is a web page, NOT an image. When you try to insert the link as an image, the html IMG tag is used to specify the FILE NAME to be inserted. The file can be on a different url but it should not refer to just another uri.

to get around it, you have 4 options:

1. Specify the image file name directly and not the uri with the img tag.
2. Use iframe and put the uri
3. use frame (I'd not go for this)
4. Use Ajax and fill it in a DIV tag - most effective in my opinion.

Comment: I still think it is because stockcharts.com blocks it.